# Load table mostly or partly into working memory for querying

Tags: sql, postgresql, caching, memory

I have a PostgreSQL read replica with the sole purpose to do some aggregate queries. Currently, a lot of I/O is going on in order to do the aggregates, even though there's a lot of memory available and since the instance serves only this purpose I was wondering if it is possible:

To simply tell PostgreSQL to cache most of the content of the table in order to speed up aggregate queries. Is that possible?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgprewarm.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Craig's comment:

> The pg_prewarm module provides a convenient way to load relation data into either the operating system buffer cache or the PostgreSQL buffer cache.
>   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgprewarm.html

Don't forget pg_prewarm is an extension, so you'll have to add it with:

```
create extension pg_prewarm;
```

> .. a lot of I/O is going on in order to do the aggregates, even though there's a lot of memory available ..

You might also want to research some of the memory config options (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY)